# Синонимизировать метки [vs2019] → [visual-studio-2019]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток

Нужно синонимизировать метки [vs2019](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs2019) → [visual-studio-2019](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2019), как это сделано по аналогии с [vs2015](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs2015) → [visual-studio-2015](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2015).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
updating post history, 32 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 30 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 28 rows affected
destroying 'vs2019': [vs2019] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 178
tag remapping of [visual-studio-2019] and [vs2019] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

Comment: Неожиданно быстро. Прям приятно видеть.